# Replacing a string with counts of streaks

Tags: python, string, list

Let's say I have a string of the following form:

```
"000000111100011100001011000000001111"
```

and I want to create a list containing the lengths of the 1-streaks:

```
[4, 3, 1, 2, 4]
```

Is there a nice one-liner for this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you don't mind the `from itertools import groupby`...

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(s) if k == '1']
[4, 3, 1, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Can be done with regex, though not quite as elegant as the itertools solutions

```
answer = [len(item) for item in filter(None, re.split(r"[^1]+", test_string))]
```

Or, more elegant:

```
answer = [len(item) for item in re.findall(r"1+", test_string)]
```

and more elegant still (credits to Jon):

```
answer = map(len, re.findall("1+", test_string))
```

Comment: Why not just use the lengths of matches to `1+`?

Comment: @icktoofay Ooh, yea that'd make this nicer, updating

Comment: How about just: `map(len, re.findall('1+', s))`

Comment: @JonClements Ooh, good call. Updated, with series of elegance

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> mystr = "000000111100011100001011000000001111"
>>> [len(s) for s in re.split("0+", mystr) if s]
[4, 3, 1, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

No regex needed, just `str.split`

```
>>> mystr = "000000111100011100001011000000001111"
>>> [len(s) for s in mystr.split('0') if s]
[4, 3, 1, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score -6):

```
>>> s = "000000111100011100001011000000001111"
>>> items = set(s)
>>> counts = [s.count(x) for x in items]
>>> counts
[1, 1]
>>>
```

Comment: Not an answer to the question.

Comment: OP even showed what the output should be, which doesn't match what you've written at all..

Comment: damn it's later than I thought... sorry

Comment: it's so bad it's kinda funny though :)

Comment: @RussW If `counts == [1, 1]` the input contained a 1 and a 0 I guess ;)